# how to get a list of built-in modules programatically

Tags: micropython

I would like to get a list of the built-in a(and frozen) modules using micropython, running on the board (ESP32) itself.

help('modules') will give you a list of all modules, but this is only send to the terminal. I have not been able to capture it on any other way.

also see [micropython forum](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3298&start=10) where the only option seems to be to use dupterm 
which unfortunately is not available on ESP32

Comment: Is seems that thonny is implementing something like this

https://github.com/thonny/thonny/blob/master/thonny/plugins/micropython/__init__.py

Comment: This would indeed be very helpfull.... we need a micropython uservoice ;-)